# screenX and screenY is affected by page zoom in and out for FireFox and IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox

I was testing a page and I wanted to get the browser position. I used screenX and screenY to do this. I had no problem when the page was at the default zoom level. But for testing purposes when I zoomed in/out the page and looked at the value for screenX and screenY it gave a me different values! This happens in both FireFox and IE in any page you load. The funny thing is this does not happen in Chrome.

Any one care to explain why this is happening and a possible solution for this?

Comment: When you zoom, `1px` at `100%` becomes `2*2px` at `200%`, so moving by the same "distance" is really only half the number of "pixels" as before.